# Mysql as database for java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am considering using MySQL as a database for a project i am working on. A very important requirement for this project is if i download it using an installer, or jar file, if i open my program will my database connection always be there? Or are there requirements and installations need for this. I don't want to start the project use MSQL and realize it doesn't fulfill this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will just request a connection to MySQL and it will, if possible, give it one, so you should not need to be worrying about that.

What you should be worried about are these:

- The MySQL database on your client's PC has the same username and password your connection uses to connect to the database.
- Any tables and/or stored procedures that your application might need to function properly.

Also, you need your client to install a MySQL server on his/her machine. You might want to make your application ask the user for some database credentials so that it can connect to the database. Your application should also check for and create, if not found, any tables or other structures it makes use of.

You might consider other database, such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) which can be embedded in your JAR file, as shown [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also MySQL needs a server being installed. There are databases like SQLite that don't require any installation.

Totally independant to this is the point if the connection is established or not. You need to establish one or more (pooled) (most likely jdbc) connections and handle their lifetime. This means your software has to react in a proper way if the connection is lost or closed actively.